# Why removeAll() is required in ListCellRenderer?

Tags: java, swing, listcellrenderer

This is my code:-

```
public class MyRender extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {

    ImageIcon on_img;
    JLabel name = new JLabel();
    JLabel icn = new JLabel();
    JLabel img = new JLabel();

    public MyRender(Atalk) {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setForeground(Color.black);
        on_img = new ImageIcon(MyCls.class.getClassLoader().getResource("imgPath"));
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value != null) {
            removeAll();
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            User user = (User) value;
            String pres = user.getPresence().toLowerCase();
            img.setIcon(default_img);
            if (pres.contains("unavailable"))
                icn.setIcon(off_img);
            else
                icn.setIcon(on_img);
            name.setText(user.getName());
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            add(img, BorderLayout.EAST);
            add(icn, BorderLayout.WEST);

            panel.add(st, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.add(name, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JLabel lbl = new JLabel(" ");
            lbl.setSize(100, 5);
            add(lbl, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);

            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                panel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            } else {
                setBackground(Color.white);
                panel.setBackground(Color.white);
            }

            return this;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have called `removeAll()` method. If I remove that line the data is not displayed properly. All data overlaps each other. And If I add `removeAll()` all works fine. Why this happens? Is it necessary to call `removeAll()`?

Comment: Normally, you don't need that. But it depends on what you have put inside your JPanel. It could be useful to show more code, in particular the constructor and the rest of getListCellRenderer.

Comment: Also note that your method should never return null.

Comment: @jfpoilpret: updated my question with class code.

Comment: @ Harry Joy ... really don't, removeAll() is job for Action (including paintBorder for JPanel) and ListCellRendered by default returns JLabel, now comings my question 1) by JButton Action you'd change JList contents and JList contains JLabel + Icon + ImageIcon 2) there is only one JList or more that one JList 3) are we talking about JList

Comment: @mKorbel: Answers:1) Yes Jlist contains JPanel which includes JLabel, ImageIcon and I also perform operations on JList later on. 2)Total 4 Jlist but all shares own `new MyRender()`. 3) yes.  Don't use space between `@` and ` person name` it will not notify that person.

Comment: @Harry Joy  1) remove everything about JPanel, removes and adds JComponents out of there and to the separete methods or voids , Renderer should be cointains only if (isSelected) { and return this 2) I not see some real reason (here) create new JPanels + JLabels on fly 3) hide JLabels inside JPanel put here small dealy with java.swing.Timer, move JPanel to the Top or Bottom (depends of direction), set Selection to previous/next Item, display JPanel vith Invisible JLabels, again small delay, setVisible(true) for JLabels :-) hmmm and sorry for my feel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to restructure your class so that all children of `MyRender` are created and added at construction time.

`getListCellRendererComponent()` should be used **ONLY** to change values or visual attributes (e.g. background) of existing components.

Don't forget that `getListCellRendererComponent()` should be as fast as possible (it can be called quite frequently), hence it should not create components but only modify existing ones.

Typically, here is how your `getListCellRendererComponent()` method should look like:

```
@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
    JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    if (value != null) {
        User user = (User) value;
        String pres = user.getPresence().toLowerCase();
        img.setIcon(default_img);
        if (pres.contains("unavailable"))
            icn.setIcon(off_img);
        else
            icn.setIcon(on_img);
        name.setText(user.getName());
        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            panel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.white);
            panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Then where should I do the processing on `User` object?

Comment: I don't understand your question; in my snippet above, I haven't moved anything related to user. The only changes I've made are related to invariant components, that should be created and added to MyRender just ocne at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. got it worked without `removeAll()`. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't have to call removeAll().  I think that your problem is that you're creating a new JPanel inside of the getListCellRendererComponent method each time the method is called here:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

If you made this JPanel a class field, you would likely not have to call removeAll.

edit: answered better by jfpoilpret.  1+ to him.

Answer (score 0):

also use `revalidate()` on panel

Comment: where to call `revalidate()`? at the end?

Comment: no you are not getting me. What I want is to get rid of `removeAll()`. With `removeAll()` all works fine no need to add anything extra.

Comment: really good advice, but if you you add some JComponents then just call revalidate(), but if you removed some JComponents, then you need to call revalidate() plus repaint(), remove -> add -> revalidate() + repaint();