# JList display error with custom ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, listcellrenderer

I am having trouble with one a custom ListCellRenderer on a JList. When there is only 1 item in the List the cell is displayed correctly, but when there is more than 1 item, each cell seams to be painted with the content of all cells overlapping each other, like this:

[image]

My CellRenderer looks like this:

```
public class SendungsCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {

private EmptyBorder eb = new EmptyBorder(5, 2, 5, 2);
private LineBorder lb = new LineBorder(new Color(255,255,255), 5);

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    uiSendungsbutton p = (uiSendungsbutton) value;
    if(isSelected){
        this.setBackground(new Color(200,200,250));
        this.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(lb, new StrokeBorder(new BasicStroke())));
    }else{
        this.setBackground(new Color(252,252,252));
        this.setBorder(lb);
    }
    this.setLayout(p.getLayout());
    this.add(p.getNamePnl(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(p.getKdnrPnl(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    return this;
    }

}
```

and it is set using

```
list_Sendung = new JList(getSendungen().toArray());
list_Sendung.setVisibleRowCount(1);
list_Sendung.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
list_Sendung.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
list_Sendung.setCellRenderer(new SendungsCellRenderer());
```

The method `getSendungen()` returns an ArrayList of `uiSendungsbutton`.

How do I get the JList to display each item in a cell of its own correctly?

Comment: **don't** store components in the JList, instead store the data which should be rendered

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042955/why-removeall-is-required-in-listcellrenderer I was facing similar problem. It might be helpful.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno not, wrong decision, forgot about, don't to set, add, remove, change `JComponent` and its status/properties in the `XxxRenderer`, please see [code how can/could be this idea works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15090127/714968), use JTable(one column without JTableHeader) instead of JList

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is that the same cell renderer is being used for all cells, and for each new cell, you add the components to `this` again. To fix this problem, remove all components from `this` each time, using `removeAll`. Your code would look like this after it was fixed:

```
public class SendungsCellRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {

    private EmptyBorder eb = new EmptyBorder(5, 2, 5, 2);
    private LineBorder lb = new LineBorder(new Color(255,255,255), 5);

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        this.removeAll();
        uiSendungsbutton p = (uiSendungsbutton) value;
        if(isSelected){
            this.setBackground(new Color(200,200,250));
            this.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(lb, new StrokeBorder(new BasicStroke())));
        }else{
            this.setBackground(new Color(252,252,252));
            this.setBorder(lb);
        }
        this.setLayout(p.getLayout());
        this.add(p.getNamePnl(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(p.getKdnrPnl(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for creating a new component on each call (and supporting the OP in his/her wrong-doing of having components in the list ;-)

Comment: +1 for explanation. I should have figured this myself. I guess if anyone actually **wanted** overlapping cells cells, they just have to use the same CellRenderer instance for each cell.

Comment: -1, for the same reason as @kleopatra you should not create new components in `getListCellRendererComponent`.

Comment: every code lines after `pane.setBorder(lb);` will killing `Renderers Concept`, agree with down_vote :-), don't to set, add, remove, change `JComponent` and its status/properties in the `XxxRenderer`, please see [code how can/could be this idea works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15090127/714968)

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno cellRenderers are _designed_ to be re-used, that is it is perfectly fine and intended to have the same instance of the rendering component. This works even if you have components as data (don't don't don't :-), provided you remove them again: otherwise there might be unpredictable painting artefacts like f.i. yours. Just for fun, let your old renderer have a FlowLayout ...

Comment: @HarryJoy actually, you _do_ need to call removeAll if you keep adding components all the time :-) The point is that you shouldn't steadily add components ...

Comment: Then edit the accepted answer with a proper version, instead of arguing in hidden comments.

Comment: @Nizil no adding a new JPanel for each item is not a working solution. If you add a new instance for each item renderer it produces the same exact result.

Comment: This isn't a working solution either. I mimicked this in my code, and the item's rendered content still stacks on each item.